# QML: Overriding a signal handler from other element

Tags: qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml

Is it possible to override an elements action (eg onTriggered() of a Timer) from within the onClick() of a button?

Something like so->

```
         Button {
                id: centerBtn
                objectName: "button"

                onClicked: {
                delaytimer.running = true;
                delayTimer.onTriggered {}; // override here

                }

                Timer {
                    id: delaytimer
                    interval: 1000
                    running: false
                    repeat: false
                    onTriggered: //something implemented here

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a property to store the code of the signal handler and reassign it when needed:

Look at the following snippet of code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 150

    Button {
        id: foo
        text: "Foo"
        onClicked: {
            delaytimer.a = function () { console.log("Foo!") };
            delaytimer.running = true;
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: bar
        text: "Bar"
        anchors.left: foo.right
        onClicked: {
            delaytimer.a = function () { console.log("Bar!") };
            delaytimer.running = true;
        }
    }

    Timer {
        id: delaytimer
        interval: 1000
        running: false
        repeat: false
        property var a: function () { console.log("will be overridden!") };
        onTriggered: a()
    }
}
```